# links on fullcalendar events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcallendar to render a calendar with events from my API.

It all works fine and also shows a tooltip on hover but I can not get it to add a link to an event.

For now I am just trying to get an event link to google.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
                events: "/app/calendar/cal/",
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                eventClick: function(event) {
                    if (event.url) {
                        window.open(event.url);
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                      $(element).tooltip({title: event.body});
                  }
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: `url` parameter has to be part of event's data. [See the doc](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/)

Answer (score 0):

For Google API, I recommend using this approach : http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/

For your answer please read this: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/

The structure is not right.